# Spring-Data-Jpa - Null pointer exception when using more than one named parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring-Data-Jpa to create my repository interface.  While specifying explicity query using @query annotation, I am seeing null pointer exception.  It happens only if I have more than one named parameter in the query, and only if I use named parameters.

```
public interface DeviceStatusRepository extends JpaRepository<DeviceStatus, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<DeviceStatus> {


    @Query(value = "SELECT ds from DeviceStatus ds where  ds.deviceId like :deviceId and ds.chargingStatus like :chargingStatus")
    Page<DeviceStatus> searchByMultipleFields(@Param("deviceId") String deviceId, @Param("chargingStatus") String chargingStatus, Pageable p);

}
```

Following is the null pointer exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StringQuery.checkAndRegister(StringQuery.java:175)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StringQuery.parseLikeBindings(StringQuery.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StringQuery.<init>(StringQuery.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.fromQueryAnnotation(SimpleJpaQuery.java:167)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:279)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:147)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:153)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 36 more
```

I did look up the [StringQuery.java](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/StringQuery.java) of Spring-Data and even placed a debug point to understand what is causing the NPE.  I noticed that `bindings` had only entry about `deviceStatus` (1st named param in my query), and while it was looking up entry for `chargingStatus` (2nd named param in my query), it gives NPE in `existing.hasPosition(binding.position)` as `position` is NULL (I guess position is expected to be null for named parameters).  Looks like a bug as it is not handling null params properly.

```
private final void checkAndRegister(LikeBinding binding) {

    for (LikeBinding existing : bindings) {
        if (existing.hasName(binding.name) || existing.hasPosition(binding.position)) {
            Assert.isTrue(existing.equals(binding), String.format(MESSAGE, existing, binding));
        }
    }

    this.bindings.add(binding);
}
```

Spring-Data-Version that I am using is 1.4.0.M1

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.M1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Please note that the query Works fine if I use positional parameter (?1, ?2) instead of named parameters (:deviceId, :chargingStatus).**

Anybody else seen this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: This has been fixed with the 1.3.4.RELEASE of Spring Data JPA. Should be available in Maven Central soon.

This is a bug. I could reproduce the issue easily and filed [a ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-373). Watch it for progress. In general, if you run into exceptions (especially NPEs) thrown from within the framework that do not explicitly express a misconfiguration or point to user code, feel free to directly create issues in the tracker. Thanks for spotting this!